# Nginx/port 80 unreachable via second nic/ip

Tags: nginx, iptables

We have two nics connected to our server. One for local network and one for remote access.

```
eth0:
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=*****
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
HWADDR=****
DEFROUTE=no
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth0"
IPADDR=193.9.9.19
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
DNS1=193.9.9.13
USERCTL=no

eth1:
DEVICE=eth1
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
UUID=****
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
HWADDR=****
IPADDR=[Public IP]
GATEWAY= [Public Gateway]
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth1"
USERCTL=no
PEERDNS=yes
```

We can access everything fine via local network 
but can only SSH but not access port 80 via the public ip.

Here's the nginx config

```
server {
    listen 193.9.9.19:80;
    listen [public ip]:80;


   root /html/test/web;
    index app.php;

   try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

   location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /app.php;
    }

}
```

IPTables

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

Things that we've tried.

1. tcpdump shows that pings and requests reach the server:  tcpdump -i eth1 "port 80"
2. requests does not reach nginx since nginx/access.log and project/access.log has no new entries
3. ssh via the public IP is working

Comment: This is a little confusing. When I go to the IP address you posted, I get redirected to the web site. So what is all this about another "public IP"?

Comment: I didn't post the public ip. 193.9.9.19 is the local ip using eth0. The public ip is on eth1

Comment: 193.9.9.19 is a public IP address and has a live website responding on it. That is not your website? What is going on here?

Comment: Nope. It's just the same ip as our internal server.

Comment: Oh, so you used someone else's public IP addresses as your own "private" IP addresses? That's going to cause you endless torture.

Comment: We had no control over that, but yeah I see your point.